# When returning an anonymous function from a function, is the function in the return statement a function declaration or function expression?

Tags: javascript

This is the code which I got stuck on.

```
var bind = function(func, thisValue) {

  return function() {

    return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);

  }

}
```

I've been learning about execution contexts and closures. My guess is that the function in the first return statement is a function expression as it's part of a statement. However, then I don't know how a closure, with reference to func and thisValue, is created.

If it is a function expression, then when bind is called, the anonymous function won't be evaluated there and then and therefore won't have a function object set up with a [[scope]] property containing the scope of bind's execution context. And so, the anonymous function won't have access to func and thisValue through it's [[scope]] property.

So if the code does indeed form a closure, then my guess is wrong and the function in the first return statement must be a function declaration. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding when return is evaluated? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

So I did some digging in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) and came to the conclusion that the anonymous function that's being returned is a function expression... and it really seems quite simple now. When defining a function using a function declaration, the identifier isn't optional and so an anonymous function can't be defined using a function declaration. Anonymous functions can only be defined using function expressions because with function expressions, the identifier is optional.

I also said this...

> If it is a function expression, then when bind is called, the anonymous function won't be evaluated there and then and therefore won't have a function object set up with a [[scope]] property containing the scope of bind's execution context.

I was wrong. The function expression is evaluated when bind() returns. Therefore, a function object is set up for it and everything is scoped as it should be.

I hope I've made some sense. If I've missed anything, please comment!

Comment: You can easily identify a function declaration: it's a statement *starting* with the `function` keyword. Everything else is a function expression. (Well, not quite, but good enough... [Further reading](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/))

Answer (score 1):

This seem quite complicated but is actually very simple. What this function does is return a function where the arguments you pass are bound to `thisValue`.

Here is an example:

```
var bind = function(func, thisValue) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
    }
}

var x = {
    "key": "the value"
};
var y = {
    "key": "the y value"
};

function alert_key() {
    alert(this.key);
}

var bound_function = bind(alert_key, x);
bound_function();   // alerts "the value"
var bound_function2 = bind(alert_key, y);
bound_function2();  // alerts "the y value"
```

It's important to realize that `this` in `this.key` is bound to `x` because it is the first argument in `func.apply(thisValue, arguments)`

`arguments` is a magic JavaScript variable that will contain all arguments passed to the function. So `func.apply(thisValue, arguments)` really only just passes all arguments along but set the `this` context to `thisValue` (or `x` and `y` in my example).

Example for extra argument(s):

```
var bind = function(func, thisValue) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
    }
}

var x = {
    "key": "the value"
};

function alert_key(another_value) {
    alert(this.key + " " + another_value);
}

var bound_function = bind(alert_key, x);
bound_function("another value");    // alerts "the value another value"
bound_function("value y");  // alerts "the value value y"
```

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this Frits! It's not exactly what I was stuck on though :-). See below.

Comment: Ah I see, I read 'closure' and skipped the rest of the question. Silly me.